# How to connect to API?

Tags: python-3.x, telethon

I am trying to start a client, but it gives a "database is closed" error.
What should I do?

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

api_id = 12345
api_hash = '##################'
phone_number = '+##########'
channel_username = 'tehrandb'

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

assert client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone_number)
    me = client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Enter code: '))
```

Comment: Please assure everyone the database  is running when your process produces that message (any more details?).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else gets the same error. `Database is closed` means that you have an already running process using the same session file (which is session_name.session in the question). The same session file can only be used by 1 process at a time so you need to kill one of them.

if you are under Linux you can use fuser session_name.session to see the list of processes using that file.